# syntax warning showing: exception is never thrown in body of try statement

Tags: java, mysql, exception

```
public class SetupConnection{

  public static Statement setCon(){
    Connection con=null;
    Statement st=null;                

    try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      con=DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zomatocrm","root","");
      st = con.createStatement();
    }
    catch(ConnectException err){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection refused!!!");
      System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }            
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());                   
    }   
    return st;
  }
```

The warning:

> exception is never thrown in body of try statement

is coming up at the `catch(ConnectException){` line.

Comment: Just remove that catch clause. As the exception says, this exception is never thrown from the try body.

Answer (score 2):

None of the code in your try block:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();     
con=DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zomatocrm","root","");
st = con.createStatement();
```

...can ever throw a `ConnectException`. Therefore the compiler is warning you that this `catch` clause:

```
catch(ConnectException err){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection refused!!!");
    System.out.println(err.getMessage());
}
```

is redundant. If you remove it, the warning will go away.

Answer (score 1):

`getConnection` and `createStatement` throw `SQLException`, which is caught in your second catch block. `ConnectException` is never thrown...

Answer (score 1):

Note, if the connection to the database fails due to network problems, you'll still only get a `SQLException`, so catching that would be better and if you want to determine whether there was a networking problem you could check the `SQLState` (according to [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-reference-error-sqlstates.html)):

```
try {
    ...
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
    if ("08S01".equals(sqle.getSQLState())) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection refused (or networking problem)!!!");
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Also (as a general point, not related to this error), your method creates a connection (`con` object), but no reference to it is ever returned, so how are you closing the connection?  Not closing a connection can lead to a connection leak, which will cause you problems.

Comment: Where were you using `con.close()` ? Because as the method stands above, you are creating a `con` object inside the `setCon` method, but it is not returned.  It may be better to return the `con` object, which means that whoever is using the `setCon()` method is then responsible for closing connection.

Comment: ya that only...i returned con latr in the code n then closed it whr i used it latr...its fine then..i guess!!!...